# ionic 4 Super-tabs iOS tab changing issue

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, supertab

I am using super-tab in home page of my ionic app. The problem is whenever i navigate from any tab to another child page and return back the first tab content showing. But tab indicator showing correct tab. The problem is only with iOS devices. It works perfectly on android devices.

**home.page.html**

```
<super-tabs>
    <super-tabs-toolbar slot="top" scrollable scrollable-padding="false">
        <super-tab-button>
          <ion-label>Dashboard</ion-label>
        </super-tab-button>
        <super-tab-button>
          <ion-label>Tab 1</ion-label>
        </super-tab-button>
        <super-tab-button>
          <ion-label>Tab 2</ion-label>
        </super-tab-button>
        <super-tab-button>
          <ion-label>Tab 3</ion-label>
        </super-tab-button>
        <super-tab-button>
          <ion-label>Tab 4</ion-label>
        </super-tab-button>
        <super-tab-button>
          <ion-label>Tab 5</ion-label>
        </super-tab-button>
    </super-tabs-toolbar>

    <super-tabs-container>
        <super-tab>
          <ion-nav [root]="tab0"></ion-nav>
        </super-tab>
        <super-tab>
          <ion-nav [root]="tab1"></ion-nav>
        </super-tab>
        <super-tab>
          <ion-nav [root]="tab2"></ion-nav>
        </super-tab>
        <super-tab>
          <ion-nav [root]="tab3"></ion-nav>
        </super-tab>
        <super-tab>
          <ion-nav [root]="tab4"></ion-nav>
        </super-tab>
        <super-tab>
          <ion-nav [root]="tab5"></ion-nav>
        </super-tab>
    </super-tabs-container>
</super-tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue. And the problem was that i used a viewChild inside one tab and used child.scrollIntoView().
The behaviour was like yours - the first tab was active but the content of the tab where i used the scrollIntoView method was shown.
Maybe this is helpful.
Best Axel